# Are there any aspects of php that could cause a page to fail loading before the first line is executed?

Tags: php, html

Basically what I have is a simple log-in form (index.php) which routes to a login.php for db processing. However whenever I run my web app and submit log-in details via index.php form, I always get stuck with a "this page isn't working" error with login.php as the url (even though the first line in login.php is an opening php tag, and the second is a die() function printing out a message[the message is never displayed when the page fails])

[image: Page-Load Fail]

Is there something else that could cause the page load to fail even though by design the first thing I'm aaware that should be happening is that the die function would be executed, thus producing my desired on-screen message?

First 2 lines of login.php

```
<?php
die("line 2 of login.php");
```

Comment: Are you loading that page directly, or are you using `include` or similar? It could also be something with your host... But 500 errors are very general, so definitely not enough for us to tell you what your issue is

Comment: Try add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very begining of the file.

Comment: Given that it's a 500 error check the error log on the server.

Comment: Check logs.  No luck?  Permissions?  Try and rewrite that page in a different editor.

Comment: could you disable ASP.NET and try loading that php script again? Your `X-Powered-By` headers show both `PHP/7.0.32` *and* `ASP.NET`

Comment: If you have a syntax error anywhere in a page, the script won't compile, and you'll get no output at all. I.e., you won't get output up to the point where the error is.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Correct. Missing semi-colon on line 23. Problem solved.

Comment: Protip: `php -l <file>` from the command line is your friend. It will instantly report syntax errors so you don't have to discover them on the web site later.